# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Below is the code of ListEmployeeComponent

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import EmployeeService from '../service/EmployeeService';


class ListEmployeeComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            employees : []
        }

        this.addEmployee = this.addEmployee.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        EmployeeService.getEmployees().then((res) => {
           this.setState({ employees: res.data});
        });
    }

    addEmployee(){
        this.props.history.push("/add-employee");
    }
....
....
export default ListEmployeeComponent
```

And this one is of App.js code

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import {BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom';
import {Routes, Route} from 'react-router';
import ListEmployeeComponent from './Component/ListEmployeeComponent';
import HeaderComponent from './Component/HeaderComponent';
import FooterComponent from './Component/FooterComponent';
import CreateEmployeeComponent from './Component/CreateEmployeeComponent';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
        <Router>
         
                  <HeaderComponent/>
                     <div className="container">
                       <Routes> 
                       <Route exact path="/" element={<ListEmployeeComponent/>}/>
                       <Route path="/employees" element={<ListEmployeeComponent/>}/>
                       <Route path="/add-employee" element={<CreateEmployeeComponent/>}/>
                       </Routes>
                     </div> 
                     
                  <FooterComponent/>
           
        </Router>
    </div>
    
  );
}

export default App;
```

I want to navigate my page to the add-employee page but when I click on that button I'm getting an error as "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')"

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: is it meant to be `<Route exact path="/" element={ListEmployeeComponent}/>`?

Answer (score 0):

import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

let history = useHistory();

In react there is useHistory hook which can be used like this instead of this.props.push. This will solve your problem.

Comment: First of all thanks a lot for helping me out... So you mean instead of writing "this.props.history.push("/add-employee")" I should add -  import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom"; let history = useHistory(); this library and use it as history("/add-employee"); ?

Comment: @KirtiSoni It depends on which version of react-router-dom you are using. With v6 the hook is called "useNavigate" and not "useHistory". You will also have to convert "ListEmployeeComponent" to a functional component to utilize react hooks.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you get the history value from the props, but when defining the component in the program, you did not add any properties called history to the component.

```
function App() {
 ...
 return (
   ...
   <Route exact path="/" element={<ListEmployeeComponent histoy={}/>}/>
   ...
 )
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because history is undefined when you call `this.props.history.push();`. You must pass that prop down to your `ListEmployeeComponent` component. You could also transform that component into a functional component like your `<App />` component so that you can utilize a hook called `useNavigate` from `react-router-dom`. Below is a snippet that shows how we could utilize `useNavigate` so that we don't have to pass props down the component tree. Again, you will need to convert your `ListEmployeeComponent` component to a functional component for this to work:
'

```js
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function LinkButton({ children }: LinkButtonProps) {
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    function handleNavigate() {
        navigate('/dashboard');
    }

    return (
        <LinkButtonComponent onClick={handleNavigate}>
            {children}
        </LinkButtonComponent>
    );
}
```